# Regex to match Text between <a href="#">Text I need</a> with 20 Maximum Character

Tags: regex

I need a regex pattern to match any text that comes between `<a href="https://website.com">Health & Beauty</a>` that may or may not include a space and/or special character "&" but should not exceed the character limit of 10. In said case, I would want to extract:

Beauty & Fashion

The following is a regix code to extract anchor text:

(<[a|A][^>]*>|)

But I want to limit the character to 1 to 10 ? Is that possble?

Comment: [Regex is really not the tool for that.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: I am using custom data grabber from scrapebox and they demand regex for that

Comment: The following is a regix code to extract anchor text:

(<[a|A][^>]*>|)

But I want to limit the character to 1 to 10 ? Is that possble?

Answer (score 1):

For PCRE:

https://regex101.com/r/GJSlZl/1

For JS:

https://regex101.com/r/FIdlyU/1

The solution depends on the regex flavor:

- js: `(?<=<a[^>]+>)([\w &]{1,10})(?=<\/a>)`
- pcre: `<a[^>]+>\K([\w &]{1,10})(?=<\/a>)`

Comment: Thanks for your Help! I really appreciate it.. Is it possible that the it doesn't extract anything that contains any number like January 2019?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're looking to find some expression similar to,

```
(?<=&|>)([^&\r\n]{0,10}(?=&|<\/a>))*
```

which you might want to add more boundaries on the left side,

```
(?<=&|>)
```

#### Test

```
$re = '/(?<=&|>)([^&\r\n]{0,10}(?=&|<\/a>))*/s';
$str = '<a>Health & Beauty</a>
<a href="https://website.com">Health & Beauty</a>
<a href="https://website.com">Health & Beauty 1 & Health & Beauty 1 </a>
<a>Health & Beauty 1 & Health & Beauty 1 </a>
<a>Health & Beauty 1 & Some other words & Beauty 1 & Some other words 2</a>

';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/80y9qA/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/80y9qA/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: Thanks for your Help! I really appreciate it.. Is it possible that the it doesn't extract anything that contains any number like January 2019? And it could have only 3 spaces max.